# Filtering records using rank

Tags: hive, bigdata

I am joining two tables contact and district and the join is returning multiple records for each city. I want to pick anyone record for each city using rank. Following is my query but it is not working. How can I correct my query?

```
    Select p.name,
    p.city,
    p.district,
    RANK() over (partition by p.city order by p.district asc) as rank 
    from (select
         d.name,
         c.city,
         c.district 
         from contact c inner join district d 
         ON d.district            = c.district
         AND d.districtType          ='d'
         AND d.nametype='2' 
         AND c.district like 'E%'
         where c.city in(1316,1515,19393,8026))p
    rank=1;
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you show some input data, actual output and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

where clause is missing before rank =1

```
 Select p.name,
    p.city,
    p.district,
    RANK() over (partition by p.city order by p.district asc) as rank 
    from (select
         d.name,
         c.city,
         c.district 
         from contact c inner join district d 
         ON d.district            = c.district
         AND d.districtType          ='d'
         AND d.nametype='2' 
         AND c.district like 'E%'
         where c.city in(1316,1515,19393,8026))p
    where rank=1;
```